# Http requests a api local em Laravel através de mobile APP em Flutter

Tags: laravel, api, http, flutter

Boa noite,

Tenho uma API em Laravel que está a ser executada apenas localmente através do Valet e estou a desenvolver uma mobile APP em Flutter onde pretendo fazer requests a essa mesma API Laravel.

Já instalei todos os plugins necessários, no entanto quando tento fazer um request à API através da APP apenas obtenho este erro:

```
I/flutter (25634): SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'pede-new.test' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
```

De acordo com o que pesquisei online já adicionei esta linha:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

no AndroidManifest.xml mas continuo com este problema.

Se tento fazer o request através do Postman não tenho qualquer problema e tudo funciona certinho.

Nota: Como emulador estou a usar um dispositivo fisico ligado por cabo.

Desde já obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: De acordo com o erro "não tem nenhum endereço associado com o hostname que tu passou"... Por se tratar de uma requisição vinda do celular, você deve por o IP da tua máquina ao invés de `127.0.0.1`, você está fazendo isso? E o celular tem que estar na mesma rede da tua API

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40018505/4623423 Dá uma olhada aqui  ou então veja o IP da máquina que está a aplicação Laravel.Supondo que o ip seja 192.168.1.X, na raiz do a aplicação roda um >>  php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.X